# Как добавить видео в приложение

Tags: android, видео

Пишу игру, и в начале игры хочу вставить ролик, но не знаю как правильно это сделать.

Думал добавить видео в проект, но так приложение будет много весить и возможно лаги, думал через Gif. Вообщем подскажите как правильно добавить видео ролик в игру?

Может есть какой то другой способ, может вообще не видео, а как-то через анимацию, вообщем прошу ваших советов кто уже сталкивался с такой ситуацией.

Добавить видео хочу в виде комиксов как делает марвел.

Answer (score 1):

Варианты:

1. Вшить видео в приложение. Плюсы - быстро, дёшево, надёжно. Минус - увеличение размера `APK` файла.
2. Заменить видео полностью программной анимацией. Плюсы - занимает минимум места. Минусы - долго, дорого, сложно, засим возможны баги анимации.
3. Вшить в приложение ссылку на видео. Плюсы - быстро, дёшево. Минус - без интернета работать не будет.

Других вариантов нет. В вашем случае советую вшить видео в приложение. Юзеры привыкли к тяжёлым играм.

Comment: а если через html и видео через ютуб?

Comment: @fcbarcafc, это 3 пункт. Без интернета работать не будет.

Comment: что скажете если сделать в Unity2d там анимацию?

Comment: @fcbarcafc, это 2 пункт. Если вы это умеете - делайте. Если нет - то не тратьте время - это сложная и долгая задача которая всего-лишь сэкономит вам пару метров размера приложения. Не стоит того.